# Changing Day Names Dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I know that with FullCalendar, you can change the day names when a calendar is first initialized by using:

```
dayNames: ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 
           'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday']
```

and replacing the names with the new ones.  I have need to change the names after the calendar has been initialized though.  I have a dropdown menu and would like to change them on the fly when it is changed without reloading the entire page.  Is there anyway to do that?

Comment: Change the day names how? Replacing what names with what new ones? Also, what is FullCalendar? A plug-in?

Comment: From what I'm reading, you should be able to use `$('#calendar').fullCalendar('setDefaults',{dayNames:[...]});`

Comment: I just tried the setDefaults method and it doesn't update them.  I wonder if something else needs to be done to refresh the view.

Comment: Did you try to switch between Views? More like a hack and a way to check what`s happening.

Answer (score 0):

currently not possible, but once this issue is done, it will be possible:
http://code.google.com/p/fullcalendar/issues/detail?id=293